# SamsungBadger doesn't work on Nougat

Tags: android, push-notification, badge

i have a problem with samsungBadger library, https://github.com/shafty023/SamsungBadger
i get the following error on nougat:

```
Writing exception to parcel

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.sec.android.provider.badge.BadgeProvider uri content://com.sec.badge/apps from pid=15661, uid=10234 requires com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE, or grantUriPermission()
  at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceWritePermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:689)
  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceWritePermission(ContentProvider.java:501)
  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:263)
  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:163)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
```

I tested this library with android 6.0 and work properly.
Can someone help me to fix this problem?
It'is very strange that android does not provide any native method to add  badge on icon.

Thanks,

Sebastiano lazzaro

Comment: Use [ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) it has been updated more recently. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/blob/master/ShortcutBadger/src/main/java/me/leolin/shortcutbadger/impl/SamsungHomeBadger.java) for SamsungHomeBadger, badging on Samsung devices changed for Lollipop and above to use android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE Intent (implemented in the DefaultBadger class in the library) instead of the old way with content://com.sec.badge/apps URI